# Consuming Events with EventFilters

Tags: validation, javafx, javafx-8, alert, eventfilter

First, can anyone explain to me, why my `MouseEvent` gets consumed no matter which `Alert`-Option I choose? I guess it has something to do with calling an `Alert` within an `EventFilter`, but thats just not yet clear to me.

```
public class EventFilterConsumeErrorExample extends Application
{
  @Override
  public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
  {
    final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox( "Check me!" );
    checkBox.setOnAction( ( event ) ->
    {
      System.out.println( "onAction: " + checkBox.isSelected() );
    } );

    checkBox.addEventFilter( MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, ( event ) ->
    {
      System.out.println( "onFilter" );

      final Alert alert = new Alert( AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Do you wonna consume this Event?" );

      if ( alert.showAndWait().get().equals( ButtonType.OK ) )
      {
        System.out.println( "Yes, consume Event" );
        event.consume();
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println( "No, do NOT consume Event" );
        //<-- Why is the Event consumed anyway? onAction won´t be called.
      }
    } );

    final BorderPane root = new BorderPane( checkBox );
    final Scene scene = new Scene( root, 400, 400 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
  }


  public static void main( final String[] args )
  {
    System.out.println( "Java Version " + System.getProperties().get( "javafx.runtime.version" ) );
    launch( args );
  }
}
```

Programm generates following output, after clicking the checkbox twice and click each dialog decision once:

> **Java Version 8.0.72-b15**
>   **onFilter**
>   **Yes, consume Event**
>   **onFilter**
>   **No, do NOT consume Event**

In both cases the checkbox does not change its state, `onAction` is not called. Anyone able to explain why the event is not properly handled by the checkbox?

Second, how would you avoid the checkbox of beeing checked on a user-based decision?

Comment: `jdk1.8.0_66` event is not being consumed here, `onAction` is called

Comment: weird, I am using `jdk1.8.0_66` myself.

Comment: It works fine for me on jdk1.8.0_71.

Comment: @crusam by the way - I am using Fedora 23

Comment: thank you both for the feedback. I am using Win7 and I just switched to the latest JDK Version (jdk1.8.0_74) and it still does not work for me. In both cases setOnAction is not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged it and my guess is that it's a bug, you should [file a bug report](http://bugreport.java.com/). The event isn't consumed as long as you remain in the EventFilter. Sometimes after that code was processed, the event appears to be consumed in the bubbling event. That's probably a side-effect of the nested eventing in the Alert class.

You can solve that problem easily by always consuming the event and setting the checkbox manually, i. e.

```
  if ( alert.showAndWait().get().equals( ButtonType.OK ) )
  {
    System.out.println( "Yes, consume Event" );
    event.consume();
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println( "No, do NOT consume Event" );
    //<-- Why is the Event consumed anyway? onAction won´t be called.

    // always consume the event
    event.consume();

    // trigger the change manually
    checkBox.setSelected(!checkBox.isSelected());

  }
```

However, you got another problem there, e. g. if a user triggers the checkbox selection event by keyboard (space bar). But you explicitly caught the mouse event, so I leave it at that (hint: you could e. g. revert the selection in the onAction event).

Tried it on Win7 x64 with Java 8u66 and Java 8u74.

Comment: thank you for confirming, that this might be a system specific bug. I began thinking that it is only a local problem in our working environment, because of the other statements, that on their systems it works as expected. Also thank you for your solution. Just hate, that in this case I have to work around a bug, but at least it will still work, when the bug should be fixed. I already had this in mind as well.

Comment: I filed a bug report. Was a bit surprised, its not on JIRA anymore ;). As soon as it is approved as a bug, I will add the bug ticket ID here.